# Infinitesimal generator's domain

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential-operators, semigroup-of-operators

I am reading a book on diffusion process and I noticed that there is a concept about semi group approach and I feel unclear about this: what is the domain of the generator $A$? Or how to describe it in a more elementary way?

> The infinitesimal generator $A$ is defined as
> $$A\phi:=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{T_t\phi-\phi}{t}$$
> for any bounded continuous function $f$ and $t>0$,
> $$T_tf(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)P_t(x,dy),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

However, when I try to search about it on google, all I see is abstract algebra which seems to be irrelavent to my question. I appreciate if someone would share some relavent material here.

Addition: Someone told me that $\left(\overline{\left\{\phi: \phi \in C_{2} \text { with compact support }\right\}},\|\cdot\|_{D(A)}\right)$ with
$\|\phi\|_{D(A)}:=\|\phi\|_{C_{0}}+\|A \phi\|_{C_{0}}$
is the domain but unsure of it. $C_2$ is the set of twice continuously differentiable function and $C_0$ is the set of continuous function which is vanishing at infinity.

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you ask about any generators $A$ or some particular generator? If your question is general, you should find some book about semigroups (e.g. Engel Nagel, One-parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations). If you are interested is a particular generator, then you should present it.

Comment: @Mateo I have typed out exactly what the generator $A$ is. My question is what is in the statement above: what is the domain of the generator $A$? The reason why I ask this question is because I only know the domain of the generator $A$ is dense, but I don't know what exactly it is. Would this be the one as mentioned in the addition part?

Comment: Domain of $A$ is the subset of $X$, the set of those $x$ for which the limit exists.

Comment: @Mateo I know this, this is why it seems not clear to me. Can you find exact/more detailed form of the set?(What does each element of the set look like?) In addition part, I give one example of the exact form of the set, but I am uncertain if it is correct.

Comment: But you didn't write how $T$ is defined, on which space, what is $A$, you didn't define $C_2$, etc. We don't have a crystal ball. It's like you asked what is the derivative, and we give you the definition, but you want to know precisely, but you didn't provide us with a function. In each case one has to calculate the $(A,D(A))$.

Comment: @$C_2$ is defined in my. statement. I have added the part for $T$.